# Plotting graph in sage

Tags: soft-question, sagemath

Is there a way to plot a (graph theory) graph in sage in such a way that physical distance between vertices is at least a threshold (say 1cm)?

Graph layouts should be the way to do it. I am looking for a solution which is not very complicated.

Context: I need to plot a cubic planar graph. The planar layout provided by sage is not very satisfactory (spring layout gives better planar drawings)

Thank you

Comment: Please provide code to produce the graph you are interested in plotting. This will make it easier for others to come up with relevant answers to your question.

Comment: @SamuelLelièvre I would be interested in a general approach towards it. I think plotting a graph without vertices overlapping is a basic functionality.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options for plotting graphs is the circular layout,
which is a way to space out vertices consistently.

```
sage: G = graphs.CubeGraph(4)
sage: G
4-Cube: Graph on 16 vertices
sage: G.plot(layout='circular')
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 49 graphics primitives
```

Other options are documented in the documentation which can be accessed by:

```
sage: G.plot?
```

One can also show the graph using javascript:

```
sage: G.show(method='js')
```

Note that one can also set the positions of the vertices explicitly,
see the `set_pos` method of graphs.

For more on `set_pos` and all graph plotting topics:

- [SageMath documentation for graph plotting](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/graphs/graph_plot.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out `G.plot?`